# What portals allow instant transit across continents?

Tags: world-of-warcraft

In World of Warcraft, what portals are there that allow you to move quickly around the continents searching for dirty rocks, weeds, or old pieces of pottery?

e.g.:

- Twilight Highlands <---> Stormwind (obviously Alliance only)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

- Stormwind and Orgrimmar to Twilight Highlands and
  vice versa.
- Stormwind and Orgrimmar to the Temple of Earth in Deepholm and vice versa.
- Stormwind and Orgrimmar to Vashj'ir.
- Stormwind and Orgrimmar to Uldum.
- Stormwind and Orgrimmar to Mount Hyjal.
- Darnassus to Exodar and vice versa.
- Undercity to Silvermoon City and vice versa.
- Darnassus, Exodar, Stormwind, Ironforge, Orgrimmar, Undercity, Thunder Bluff, and Silvermoon City to the Blasted Lands.
- Temple of Earth in Deepholm to Therazane faction in Deepholm and vice versa.
- Shattrath to Caverns of Time (Tanaris).  This is not a normal
  portal, you need to talk to the
  Keeper of Time faction member in the
  World's End Tavern and have a
  reputation of Revered or above.  The
  reputation requirement may have been
  dropped.
- Shattrath to the Isle of Quel'Danis.
- Dalaran to Caverns of Time (Tanaris).
- Ungoro Crater (northern edge, only accessible by flying) to Sholazar Basin and vice versa.
- The Kirin Tor rings that can teleport you to Dalaran (also not a
  portal, costs about 6,000 gold but is
  class and profession agnostic).
- The Blessed Medallion of Karabor can teleport you to the Black Temple entrance in  Shadowmoon Valley in the Outlands, but this may be infeasible to obtain given it requires a long quest chain and a successful Illidan kill.
- The Outlands side of the Dark Portal to Stormwind and Ogrimmar.

That's the extent I can think of off the top of my head now that they've removed the portals in Dalaran and Shattrath.

Some professions and classes have other portals/transport abilities but I won't list them since it sounds like you want the generic options.

Comment: Horde have cataclysm-zone equivalent portals in Orgrimar. You also missed Shattrath to Quel'danas.

Comment: Cheers, you're right.  Updated.

Comment: By the way, if you're looking for an optimal Archaeology strategy in my experience the best way is to have your Hearthstone in Stormwind and use it for southern Eastern Kingdoms and then the portals for elsewhere: Twilight Highlands for northern EK, Mount Hyjal for northern Kalimdor and Uldum for southern Kalimdor.  Northrend and Outlands are smallish enough to use flight paths or a 280%/310% mount if you have one.

Comment: I added the Horde equivalents, although it won't show up until peer reviewed.

Comment: After completing a long quest line including killing the end-boss of Black Temple, you get the Blessed Medallion of Karabor, which has the on-use property to teleport to the BT entrance in Outlands. As you included the Kirint Tor rings, this one should not go unmentioned. I still have mine, and used it for archaeology a lot!

Comment: There is a portal between Un'goro and Northrend (both ways). Combined with the portal to Uldum, this might even be faster than waiting for the direct boat/zeppelin to Northrend.

Comment: If you're going to include the Blessed Medallion, you may also want to include the Argent Tourney Tabard, which ports you to there, the Baradin's Wardens/Hellscreams Reach tabards, which port you to, Tol Barad, and the guild reward cloaks, which provide a port to SW/Org.

Comment: Why not Atiesh too? Though on second thought, since it's no longer obtainable... (and the benefits of an Anywhere -> Karazhan teleport is limited. Portal to Stormwind / Stonard give you effectively the same area)

Comment: This question just begs for an image...

Comment: Added two portals I just found out about - one each to Stormwind and Ogrimmar either side of the Dark Portal (Outlands side).  Means you can portal from any capital city to those two if you use the portal to the Blasted Lands, walk through the portal and then head to your faction's side (left or right).